# How to Restart a loop from first in php

Tags: php

Here I have 2 machines I need to Allocate products for those machines. Each machine has the 50 products capacity, so if I have 100 products, first 50 to the first machine and second 50 to the second machine, the above concept is working fine, but if my products count is 150, then the allocation should be  first 50 to first machine , second 50 to Second machine, then the third 50 to First machine ,

```
$CountMachine=2;
$balanceQty=150;
$Loopcount=1;
foreach($FetchMachine as $i => $row){ //array has 2 records
     //allocated 50 products
     $balanceQty=$balanceQty-50;
     if($Loopcount==$CountMachine && $BalanceQty>0){
   $i=0; //herei got stuck , how to restart the loop from here, if the balance quantity is greater than 0 but loop excution is completed
  }
    }
$Loopcount++;
```

Comment: You should try to put your foreach loop inside a "while" loop with your conditions instead of setting $i to 0

Comment: @HabibKechrid Let me try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $CountMachine=2;
 $balanceQty=150;
 while($balanceQty>0){
 foreach($FetchMachine as $i => $row){ //array has 2 records
      //allocated 50 products
      $balanceQty=$balanceQty-50;

     }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

If your criteria is to reduce `$balanceQty` to 0, this should be the condition of your loop instead of using a `foreach` loop. You can use an index variable to reproduce looping on your machines.

Using the following solution instead of a nested foreach will prevent you to keep looping on all your machines when all quantities are already attributed (if you don't add extra checks, using nested foreach will reduce `$balanceQty` to a negative value and allocate more than exists to your machines):

```
$CountMachine=count($FetchMachine);
$i=0;
$balanceQty=150;
while($balanceQty>0){
    //allocated 50 products using $i
    $balanceQty -= 50;
    $i++;
    if($i >= $CountMachine){
        $i = 0;
    }
}
```